# Sqlachemy, Recursively fetch children and ancestors with relations

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

using properties and hybrid transformers did a little help in traversing the following trees;

```
class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(400), index=True, unique=True)

    children = db.relationship("Category", cascade='all, delete-orphan', backref=db.backref("child", remote_side=[id]))
    parents = db.relationship("Category", cascade='all', backref=db.backref("back", remote_side=[id]))
    entries = db.relationship("Feeds", backref='entry', lazy='dynamic')


class Feeds(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'feeds'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    name = (db.String(400), index=True, unique=True)

    @property
     def parents(self):
         allparents=[]
         p = self.children
         while p:
             allparents.append(p)
             p = p.children
         return allparents
```

I have a simple object

```
catlist = db.session.query(Category).filter_by(id=1).all()
```

1. How do I traverse all the tree to to get the children having variable tree depth
   i.e  Ancestor -> parent -> children -> sub-child?
2. how do i get only a sub-child object?

The same for the Feed model,  how do I traverse the ancestors tree, and how do I get only the top ancestor node?

this is what I have done so far which seems not work well apart from the property object which generated an error

```
catlist = db.session.query(Category).filter_by(id=1).all()
for cat in catlist:
    cat[0].children



File "/home/afidegnum/PycharmProjects/store/core/model.py", line 45, in children
    p = self.children
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: @antonio_antuan Postgres

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Postgresql you can use recursive queries. In your case, you can use the methods:

```
@staticmethod
def get_parents_list(category_id):
    beginning_getter = Session.query(Category).\
        filter(Category.id == category_id).cte(name='parent_for', recursive=True)
    with_recursive = beginning_getter.union_all(
        Session.query(Category).filter(Category.id == beginning_getter.c.parent_id)
        )
    return Session.query(with_recursive)

@staticmethod
def get_children_list(category_id):
    beginning_getter = Sesion.query(Category).\
            filter(Category.id == category_id).cte(name='children_for', recursive=True)
    with_recursive = beginning_getter.union_all(
            Session.query(Category).filter(Category.parent_id == beginning_getter.c.id)
        )
    return Session.query(with_recursive)
```

Invocation :

```
all_children = Category.get_children_list(1).all()
```

The query will be like this:

````
WITH RECURSIVE children_for(id, name, parent) AS
(SELECT id, name, parent
FROM categories
WHERE category.id = 1 UNION ALL id, name, parent
FROM categories, children_for
WHERE categories.parent = children_for.id)
 SELECT children_for.id, children_for.name, children_for.parent
FROM children_for;```
````